# Show First instance of records with duplicate values in colum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these values in a table called `galley_images`:

```
id    gallery_id    image_id
1             1            1
2             1            2
3             1            3
4             2            4 
5             2            5 
6             2            6 
7             2            7
8             3            8
```

I want to return the results like this:

```
id    gallery_id    image_id
1             1            1
4             2            4
8             3            8
```

Basically I only want the first instance of any record with a unique `gallery_id`.

I have a solution using Access DB but need a solution for MySQL, Access solution was:

```
SELECT id, First(gallery_id) AS FirstOfgallery_id,  
           First(image_id) AS FirstOfimage_id
FROM galley_images 
GROUP BY id
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some additional to John Woo's solution:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    gallery_images a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT gallery_ID, MIN(id) id
        FROM gallery_images 
        GROUP BY gallery_ID
    ) b
        ON a.gallery_ID = b.gallery_ID AND
            a.id = b.id
```

we must get by minimum record id's not by min(image_id) cause image_id can be coming in different order.

Comment: As well as this can I pull other related data from another table too?

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind the subquery is to select the *minimum* `ID` for each `gallery_ID`. Then join it against itself to get all the columns of the table (*if any*).

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    gallery_images a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT gallery_ID, MIN(image_ID) minID
            FROM gallery_images 
            GROUP BY gallery_ID
        ) b
            ON a.gallery_ID = b.gallery_ID AND
                a.image_ID = b.minID
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b1f0/1)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    SELECT * 
  FROM   galley_images t
  JOIN 
       ( SELECT gallery_id,
                MIN(image_id) as image_id
         FROM   galley_images
         GROUP BY gallery_id )a
  ON   t.gallery_id    =a.gallery_id    
  AND  t.image_id=a.image_id
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c0f8/4)

Comment: That downvoting is weird, this answer was the first to come out, and still another answer that is ditto copy of this got a +1, while this got -1! +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, gallery_id, image_id FROM galley_images WHERE id IN (
        SELECT MIN(ID) 
        FROM gallery_images 
        GROUP BY gallery_ID
    )
```